# HLG-40H-20B class 2 power supply to a 24 LED 's (stage) light and regular power extension

Tags: led-strip

I would like to know which wires in a HLG-40H-20B class 2 power supply (output +20V ... 2.0A     i am supposed to connect to a 24 LED 's (stage) light and the regular power (extension)

Comment: Don't know what the connections to the light look like, nor what voltage or current it needs to operate.  The powersupply datasheet is easy enough to find.  Can you post the make and model of the light, or even better a link to the datasheet for the light?

Comment: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/260/HLG-40H-spec-23844.pdf

Comment: HLG-40H-20B class 2 input 277VAC  0.23A 50/60Hz N. America only

Answer (score 0):

The type B, on one end you have one cable with three conductors, Brown Blue and Green, The Blue (Neutral) and Brown (Live) is your AC power input, and the Green is the ground.

The Red(+) and Black(-) on the other end go to the LEDs.

The Blue and White are the dimmer wires, if you want full 2 Amp to go to the LEDs, then leave the Blue and White open.

[image]

That being a 20V driver, how are the LEDs laid out?  However they are wired, I think you may have a problem. Seeing they cannot be in series, there must be some in parallel if a 20V driver is going to light them up.  At that current any parallel strings will be unbalanced, getting different amount of current where thermal runaway could be an issue.

If the parallel strings eachj have a current linmitng resistor, that will not help, and the resistors will only waste power.

Comment: Ya, im lookin at this picture and it reads HLG-40H-54B

Comment: sorry, the one I have is a 20B. the led lights are on one 5"x6" flimsy plastic panel there are 24 lights in 4 rows, and there are two wires one white and one blk & white

Comment: @reverendlisa Mine is a B, just a different voltage, 54v vs. your 20v.  You can see the number in big letters.  If it does not look like mine, you do not have a HLG-40H-xxB.  I have nearly every type of HLG and HEP that Mean Well makes, and none have a flimsy plastic anything or LED lights.  Post a pic of yours.